# Parsing XML with multiple similar child nodes in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

My response xml from webservice is like this:

```
<doc>
<str name="stage1">data1</str>
<date name="stage2">2013-08-23T09:25:12Z</date>
<str name="parent">data3</str>
<str name="stage4">xxx</str>
```

How to get the value of element stage4. My final output needs to be xxx. 
I have tried the following code:

```
Stream stream = r.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
            XDocument docs = XDocument.Load(stream);

var data = docs.element(doc).element(stage4);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = (string)docs.Root.Elements("str")
               .FirstOrDefault(str => (string)str.Attribute("name") == "stage4");
```

Or with XPath

```
string data = (string)docs.XPathSelectElement("//str[@name='stage4']");
```

Comment: What if the doc tag is a descendent of another xml. using (string)docs.descendent("doc").XPathSelectElement("//str[@name='stage4']"); seems not working

Comment: @user3083435 you can use `Descendtants` (which looks all descendant elements in file) instead of `Elements` (which looks only direct children). Or you can specify full path like `Root.Element("doc").Elemtents("str")`

Comment: Thank for your advise. Good to know there are so many ways to parse an xml.